# How can i convert it to laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a simple question for u.
How can i convert it to laravel?

Native php

```
<form method="post">
<input type="button" name="button">
</form>
<?
if(isset($_POST["button"])){
    echo "its work";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy Moly....

> I highly recommend you to read the [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5).

routes/web.php

```
<?php    
Route::get('form', 'TestController@form')->name('form');
Route::post('form', 'TestController@submit');
```

App\Http\Controllers\TestController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function form()
    {
        return view('form');
    }

    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $request->validate([
            // validation here
            // 'input' => 'rule'
        ]);

        dd($validator);
    }

}
```

resources/views/form.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('form') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
```